# export UnsubscribePromise but got Promise<Codec>

Tags: polkadot-js

i try to subscribe a account change event by code follow document https://polkadot.js.org/docs/api/start/api.query.subs

```typescript
  const unsub = api.query.system.account(address, (acc) => console.log);
```

it tells the unsub will be a UnsubscribePromise type.
but it actully return Promise<Codec> type.

how can i get the UnsubscribePromise Type to unsubscribe it.

update

i wrote a demo code

[deom code](https://github.com/kulame/subtest/blob/e82e1b288c650ecb1aeec802967aebfc732fb6cf/src/pok/pok.ts#L3)

and try to compile it.

```
➜  sub git:(master) pnpm build

> sub@0.0.0 build /srv/tmp/sub
> tsc && vite build

src/pok/pok.ts:6:53 - error TS7006: Parameter 'acc' implicitly has an 'any' type.

6     const unsub = await api.query.system.account('',acc =>console.log);
                                                      ~~~

src/pok/pok.ts:10:5 - error TS2349: This expression is not callable.
  Type 'Codec' has no call signatures.

10     unsub()
       ~~~~~


Found 2 errors in the same file, starting at: src/pok/pok.ts:6

 ELIFECYCLE  Command failed with exit code 2.
```

it tells me Type 'Codec' has no call signatures.

update 2

i make a workspace on gitpod

[demo workspace](https://kulame-subtest-4t9s5ehgr99.ws-us52.gitpod.io)

it can show the error message on terminel tab.

Answer (score 3):

You are trying to use TypeScript results (static code analysis) without having augmentation applied. See the JS API [TS augmentation FAQ](https://polkadot.js.org/docs/api/FAQ#since-upgrading-to-the-7x-series-typescript-augmentation-is-missing) on how to apply the correct types for your environment.

Effectively while the runtime is correctly decorated in all cases, for TypeScript you need to apply the augmentation overrides for your specific chain to help at coding-analysis time - here it doesn't have access to the on-chain metadata. Since all chains are different (different methods, arguments, etc.) for the static analysis the editors needs a bit of help to "pick the right one".

An example of applying augmentation for TS -

```js
// apply augmentation first, before any usage
import "@polkadot/api-augment"

// normal imports
import { ApiPromise, WsProvider } from "@polkadot/api"

// do stuff
async function main () {
    const api = await ApiPromise.create({
        provider: new WsProvider("wss://kusama-rpc.polkadot.io")
    })

    // hu is VoidFn
    // hdr is Header
    const hu = await api.rpc.chain.subscribeAllHeads((hdr) =>
        console.log(hdr.number.toString())
    )

    // qu is VoidFn
    // acc is FrameSystemAccountInfo
    const qu = await api.query.system.account("", (acc) =>
        console.log(acc.consumers.toNumber())
    )

    // unsubscribe
    qu()
    hu()
}
```

Comment: i applied explicitly but pnpm build also failed

Comment: This is the correct answer for TS augmentation.

Comment: But the result of my implementation according to the document here is still wrong @jaco.
the code is https://github.com/kulame/api-test-4450/blob/master/index.ts
and it raise errror  index.ts:22:2 - error TS2349: This expression is not callable.
  Type 'Codec' has no call signatures.

Comment: Added an example to my post above (small adaptation of my test code with comments as to what is in the editor visible and in the runtime - all due to the augmentation being applied first)

Comment: I understand what you mean. My confusion now is that it cannot compile through tsc.
my demo code also append  "import "@polkadot/api-augment""  before any usage

Answer (score 1):

you need to `await` to get the `unsub` fn.

```js
const unsub = await api.query.system.account(address, (acc) => console.log);
```

For example:

```js
const address = ""
const unsub = await api.query.system.account(address, (acc) => console.log);
console.log(unsub)
```

will print

```js
()=>l.unsubscribe()
```

Thanks!

Comment: when i try to await the api call. it return a Codec type. not the UnsubscribePromise type

Comment: I just edit my answer with a little snippet you can run in https://polkadot.js.org/apps/#/js

Comment: hmm.. thanks a lot ...
I use this tool for the first time.   the polkadot console show this message/



```
14752/X3</I</<@https://polkadot.js.org/apps/main.cd1ae65a.js:19:530635
14752/X3</I</<@https://polkadot.js.org/apps/main.cd1ae65a.js:19:530635
```

is it correct?

Comment: i worte a demo code on this issue