# Polkadot js API Type Issue

Tags: polkadot-js, polkadot

I am getting type as `Codec` while using `api.query.<module><method>`. The types should be specific or am i missing something. Is there any way to convert this into the right type.

Answer (score 6):

Remember that the full types are only available at runtime, i.e. all the endpoints and methods and their types are available in the on-chain runtime via metadata

When operating in a TypeScript environment, this means you would need to apply static types "augmented" for your specific chain - no two Substrate-based chains are the same

The [pjs api docs](https://polkadot.js.org/docs/api/FAQ#since-upgrading-to-the-7x-series-typescript-augmentation-is-missing) has a section detailing how to apply augmentation.

It has [also been covered before](https://substrate.stackexchange.com/a/3618/627) in another answer which has code samples which I am shortening below with attribution to the answer linked -

```js
// apply augmentation first, before any usage
import "@polkadot/api-augment"

// normal imports
import { ApiPromise, WsProvider } from "@polkadot/api"

// ... all code with augmented types follow
```

Answer (score -3):

Take a look at this https://github.com/Supercolony-net/typechain-polkadot, we are working on it, and in the future, there will be a lot of new features!

Comment: "to improve developers’ experience working with ink! smartcontracts" - this is not an ink! question.